# Can I configure emacs to run a custom function when its dock icon is clicked?

Tags: macos, emacs, daemon

I'm trying to set up Emacs as a daemon on Mac OS X. The major issue I'm running into is that if I close all the open frames, the remaining GUI elements (menu bar and dock icon) become nonfunctional for emacs until an new frame is opened by running `emacsclient -c` in a terminal. I don't know much about application programming in OS X, but I assume that when I click on the dock icon for Emacs, or launch it some other way while it is running, it triggers some sort of "activate" event. Is there any way for me to "catch" this event in elisp and run a custom function instead of the default behavior? (The custom function would create a new frame if Emacs is running as a daemon and no GUI frame is currently visible.)

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Emacs.  Might be worth reporting with `M-x report-emacs-bug`; in the end you might not need this magic workaround :)

Comment: Aquamacs has a command-line tools installation option.  Check to see if Emacs regular (--with-ns) has this also.

Comment: It sounds like your talking about a start-up hook or an after-init hook or a before-init hook.

Comment: You can also create your own Application with Automator or Platapus and custom design it do things you want before or after activating Emacs.  Then just place your custom application on the dock.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but they are not ideal. I'm not looking for a start-up hook. I'm talking about a situation when Emacs is *already* running as a daemon with no open frames and I click on its icon to activate it. A custom application using Platypus is also not ideal because then I would have two emacs icons in the dock: one for the actual application, and another for my custom launcher.

Comment: I think the best choice might be to tweak emacs so that instead of closing the last frame, it just hides the application instead.

Comment: The following link contains a few different options for controlling Emacs with an Applescript, which could be wrapped into an application and placed on the dock, or run from the terminal, or run with Keyboard Maestro, or a keyboard shortcut defined within System Preferences, or a variety of other methods:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366836/most-efficient-method-of-activating-an-emacs-function-with-an-applescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, I came up with a workaround for this. Whenever the last GUI frame is closed and Emacs is not quitting, it creates a new hidden GUI frame. This makes sure that as long as Emacs is running, a GUI frame exists.

Edit: Now an Emacs package: https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/osx-pseudo-daemon