# Most efficient method of activating an Emacs function with an applescript

Tags: emacs, applescript, elisp

Is there a better method to activate a function in Emacs with an applescript instead of opening the minibuffer to launch the function?  There is a delay that is needed to take my finger off of the control key to launch the applescript with a keyboard shortcut (so that Emacs doesn't register it as a command), and there is another delay after typing the name of the function into the minibuffer.  Ideally, I'd like to tell Emacs under-the-hood to run a particular function *without opening the minibuffer*.  The following is a simple applescript to activate Emacs, and open the minibuffer with `M-x`, and type the name of the function (`dock`), and press the return key.  The method should work whether Emacs is presently open (hidden or in the front) or closed.

FYI:  For the novice programmers like myself, here is a cheat-sheet for key codes:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/how-do-i-automate-a-key-press-in-applescript/36947#36947?newreg=9adf36816f4245d69f0900ec09588057

---

**EDIT**:  A shorter method would be to set up a keyboard shortcut within Emacs that is attached to a function `(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") (lambda () (interactive) (dired "/Applications")))` -- e.g., F6 to activate the function, and then use `key code 97` for the F6 key.  However, it would still be nice to learn how to specify running an Emacs function by name (with an applescript) without opening the minibuffer.

---

```
tell application "System Events"
  tell application "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs" to activate
  delay .3
  key code 53 # escape
  key code 7 # x
  key code 2 # d
  key code 31 # o
  key code 8 # c
  key code 40 # k
  delay .1
  key code 36 # return
end tell
```

**or**

```
tell application "System Events"
  tell application "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs" to activate
  delay .3
  key code 97 # F6
end tell
```

---

**EDIT**:  Revised draft (based on the answer by @Francesco) -- it requires that `(server-start)` be inside the Emacs startup file (e.g., `init.el`).  IF Emacs GUI is already running, then run `emacsclient` without a pause prior thereto; ELSE, launch Emacs GUI (pause 1 second for the server to load) and then run `emacsclient`.

```
on is_running(appName)
  tell application "System Events" to (name of processes) contains appName
end is_running
set EmacsRunning to is_running("Emacs")
if EmacsRunning then
  tell application "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs" to activate
  do shell script "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient -e '(dired \"/Applications\")'"
else
  tell application "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs" to activate
  delay 1
  do shell script "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient -e '(dired \"/Applications\")'"
end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about applescript, but can't you use [`emacsclient`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html#Emacs-Server) to do this?

Once you have started the server in your existing Emacs instance (<kbd>M-x</kbd>`server-start`<kbd>RET</kbd>), you can run something like :

```
emacsclient -e "(call-interactively 'dock)"
```

to evaluate arbitrary lisp code into Emacs.

Comment: I've created a working draft (by updating the question) based on your suggestion and included `(server-start)` in my `init.el`.  Your solution is indeed a viable alternative -- thank you very much.

Comment: Does this require daemon? The version of Emacs I'm using (emacs-mac-port) doesn't support daemon. I get `$ emacsclient -e "(call-interactively 'dock)" nil` (and the function does not get called).

Comment: Is there a way to do this calling GUI Emacs? Something like this? `(open -a /Applications/Emacs.app "$@") -e "(call-interactively 'dock)"`