# Org-Mode capture keybinding from outside Emacs on OSX

Tags: emacs, osx-yosemite, org-mode

Inside of emacs, I use 'C-c c' to make an org-capture.
I would like to bind the same key (or some function key) to perform the same function even if emacs is not the currently open window.

Is there a way to tell OS X when pressing 'C-c c' (or f10, say) to change the window to Emacs, and then perform a org-mode capture?

Comment: There is a plist setting inside of Emacs that is disabled by default, which prevents it from receiving instructions from an applescript.  This can be enabled, but instructions will be limited to things dealing with frames and so forth, not instructions in `elisp`.  It is possible to use emacsclient and send `elisp` instructions to emacs using an applescript, but this not ideal.  In a nutshell, I'd just switch to Emacs and then press your org-capture command like regular.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366836/most-efficient-method-of-activating-an-emacs-function-with-an-applescript

Comment: Here is a link to my bug report/ feature request to enable the plist to receive instructions from an applescript -- there was zero interest by anyone on the Emacs development team (i.e., no response):  https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2014-08/msg00487.html  The previous link in the comment above contains alternative methods for pressing buttons and so forth with an applescript -- again, not as ideal as passing `elisp`, but perhaps a viable workaround -- however, you'll be dealing with time issues -- e.g., wait a certain amount of time before executing next key press, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There a post on thinknix.net [http://www.thinknix.net/2015/02/19/cross-platform-system-wide-org-capture/] which will do what you want using Keyboard Maestro or for Automator if you don't have KM.

I include parts of the post here for completeness:

> There are two ways I’ve accomplished this. The first is to use Keyboard Maestro if you already have it. Create a new macro called
>   Org-Capture that triggers on F9. Have it Activate Emacs, simulate
>   keystroke Control-C, and simulate keystroke C.
>
> If you don’t have Keyboard Maestro, you can use the following
>   Applescript in Automator:

```
on run {input, parameters}

tell application "Emacs"
activate
tell application "System Events"
keystroke "c" using {control down}
keystroke "c"
end tell
end tell

return input
end run
```

> Save it as a service, and then in the Keyboard Shortcuts panel assign
>   the service to F9.

Comment: please include the information from the link in your answer. the link could be broken in the future which would make your answer useless

Comment: This worked the first time inside of automator. However later when I returned to automator and tried rerunning the script it only switches to Emacs but doesn't run the capture. Strange.